# How to do an RSpec oneliner to test a :count change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

we all love oneliners, they are so cool
but they are also so undocumented

how can I do an oneliner of this code (that currently works brilliantly)?

```
it "deletes the user" do
  expect { destroy_user }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
end
```

Comment: If by "one-liners" you mean something like `it { is_expected_to ...}`, then (FWIW) I tend to _not_ use them, even when possible. Main reason is that their auto-generated textual description is garbage in most cases.

Comment: Ahhh now I see and I agree with @SergioTulentsev. What you have now is far superior from a readability and documentary standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I do an oneliner of this code

You can't. The [one-liner syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax) is defined in terms of `subject` and this test doesn't use one at all. Furthermore, to quote the documentation:

> The one-liner syntax only works with non-block expectations (e.g.
>   `expect(obj).to eq`, etc) and it cannot be used with block expectations
>   (e.g. `expect { object }`).

Comment: well, `destroy_user` could easily be a subject   

`subject(:destroy_user) { delete admin_user_path(user) }`

Comment: @Salomanuel: That's another line. Hardly a one-liner then, is it? :) Still, no way around the other limitation (I think)

Answer (score 1):

I think your example is the only way to perform what you want.

Rspec does have [one-liner syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax) but it's only for when your block has a subject and doesn't seem to support actions like `destroy_user`.